# Positioning in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have tried to optimize our site for internet explorer. I have problems with one name `Etika`, on the first page of our website.

It would be nice, if some of you could point out, why IE behaves so strange. Here is what it looks like in IE  - [screenshot http://menu.fo/images/fail.png](http://menu.fo/images/fail.png)

You can see the live website on [menu.fo](http://menu.fo).

`Etika` should be the first one on the site.

Comment: When I run IE8 in IE7 mode I see the Etika text in the position in your screenshot, and then when the page is fully loaded it's in the right position. When I turn off scripting, it's in the right position. I wonder if it's something to do with one of the scripts you use.

Answer (score 1):

Through some trial and error, it seems to me that this is caused by the two lines

```
$('.InfoContainer').hide();
$('.InfoContainer:first').show();
```

near the beginning of your "box" script (http://menu.fo/js/box). I'm not sure exactly why, but due to some quirk in IE7's page rendering hiding the 3 InfoContainer divs and then showing the first is causing the Etika text to be pushed down.

There are probably other solutions to this, but one possibility is to change the positioning of the InfoContainer divs to absolute (which just removes them from the page flow). You can do this by adding

```
position: absolute;
right: 400px; /* width - right margin */
```

for .InfoContainer in your css file. You might have to make some adjustments to get the divs exactly where you want them.